# My Zend Framework 'quoting' mess

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework, quoting

I've got a probably very simple issue to which I can't find a satisfactory (subjectively seen) answer in the Zend Framework manual or elsewhere...

There are so many ways how I can hand over my php variables to my sql queries that I lost the overview and probably I lack some understanding about quoting in general.

#### Prepared Statements

```
$sql =  "SELECT this, that
        FROM table
        WHERE id = ? AND restriction = ?";

$stmt = $this->_db->query($sql, array($myId, $myValue)); 
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

I understand that with this solution I don't need to quote anything because the db handles this for me.

#### Querying Zend_Db_Table and _Row objects over the API

$users = new Users();

```
a) $users->fetchRow('userID = ' . $userID);  
b) $users->fetchRow('userID = ' . $users->getAdapter()->quote($userID, 'INTEGER'));  
c) $users->fetchRow('userID = ?', $userID);  
d) $users->fetchRow('userID = ?', $users->getAdapter()->quote($userID, 'INTEGER'));
```

### Questions

I understand that a) is not ok because it's not quoted at all. But what about the other versions, what's the best? Is c) being treated like a statement and automatically quoted or do I need to use d) when I use the ? identifier?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** This information is valid as of the original posting date of this answer. ZF changes often, this information may become outdated with future releases, however, this will remain unchanged for archival purposes.

If you pass a string to the `fetchRow()` method of a subclass of `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract` (which you are doing), it will be treated as a `where` part of a `Zend_Db_Table_Select` instance.

In other words, internally, `Zend_Db_Table` does this:

```
if (!($where instanceof Zend_Db_Table_Select)) {
    $select = $this->select();

    if ($where !== null) {
        $this->_where($select, $where);
    }
```

So...:

```
a) $users->fetchRow('userID = ' . $userID);
```

Is not quoted at all.

```
b) $users->fetchRow('userID = ' . $users->getAdapter()->quote($userID, 'INTEGER'));
```

Is manually quoted as an integer.

```
c) $users->fetchRow('userID = ?', $userID);
```

Is automatically quoted by `Zend_Db_Adapter_*::quoteInto()`

```
d) $users->fetchRow('userID = ?', $users->getAdapter()->quote($userID, 'INTEGER'));
```

Is actually double quoted, once by you, and once via the automatic quoting.

As far as "best" is concerned, I would recommend option C. The framework will automatically call `quoteInto` on the parameterized value.

**Keep in mind:** You could always pass an instance of `Zend_Db_Table_Select` or `Zend_Db_Select` to the `fetchRow()` method instead...

Again, in a subclass of `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract`, that would look like this:

```
$this->fetchRow($this->select()->where('userID = ?', $userID));
```

The plus of doing this, is that you can construct much more complex queries, as you have control over much, much more than just the `WHERE` clause of the SQL query. In theory, you could easily do:

```
$select = $this->select()->where('userID = ?', $userID)
                         ->join(array('sat' => 'superAwesomeTable'), array('sat.user_id = userID', array('superAwesomeColumn'));

$this->fetchRow($select);
```

**Note:** If passed an instance of `Zend_Db_Select`, the `fetchRow()` method acts exactly like `fetchAll()` *except* it internally calls the `limit()` method of the select object, with a parameter of `1`.

Answer (score 0):

I got used to

```
$where = $this->getAdapter()->quoteInto('name = ?', $name);
$this->fetchRow($where);
```

Comment: well that seems a rather bad choice since it's quoting twice and not even making use of the Zend_Db_Select properly

Comment: Not it's definetly not quoted twice ;) AFAIK it's not needed to use Z_DB_Select for simple queries. It cost resources and time to build the SQL statement from objects ;)